# No puedo instalar angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Cuando esta instalando se corta, y me lanza esto

> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
>   https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm ERR! code EEXIST
>   npm ERR! path
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng npm
>   ERR! dest C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng npm ERR! EEXIST: file
>   already exists, cmd shim
>   'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng'
>   -> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng' npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng npm ERR! Remove the existing file
>   and try again, or run npm npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files
>   recklessly.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-09T15_51_02_137Z-debug.log

Comment: El error se produce por un archivo que ya existe.  Al final dice que remuevas el archivo e intentes de nuevo o que ejecutes  el comando con  `--force` para sobreescribir los archivos. Prueba eso. Sería algo así: `npm install -g @angular/cli --force`

Comment: Ohhh muchas gracias con el --force se me soluciono!!

Answer (score 1):

Me funcionó esto:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --force
```

Como dice [Lobos en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344707/no-puedo-instalar-angular/588704#comment623251_344707):

> El error se produce por un archivo que ya existe. Al final dice que remuevas el archivo e intentes de nuevo o que ejecutes el comando con `--force` para sobreescribir los archivos. Prueba eso. Sería algo así: `npm install -g @angular/cli --force`